# Comparing area between two matrices with multiple points of intersection (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, correlation, area

I have two matrices that contain the points for the top boundaries of two jigsaw puzzles. I am trying to calculate the area contained between these two matrices (of unequal rows). They have multiple points of intersection. The picture below gives a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. The output should be a numerical value (of the total area highlighted in blue). If this is too difficult to achieve, is there a better way to compare matrices to see which ones "fit" the best?

Un-Highlighted Picture
[image: Area Un-Highlighted]
Area(in blue) that I am trying to calculate (numerical value)
[image: Area Highlighted]

The matrix values are below if it helps:

Matrix 1:

```
     1     1
     2     2
     3     2
     4     2
     5     2
     6     3
     7     3
     8     3
     9     3
    10     3
    11     3
    12     2
    13     2
    14     2
    15     2
    16     2
    17     2
    18     2
    19     2
    20     2
    21     2
    22     2
    23     2
    24     2
    25     2
    26     2
    27     2
    28     2
    29     2
    30     2
    31     2
    32     2
    33     2
    34     2
    35     2
    36     2
    37     2
    38     2
    39     2
    40     2
    41     2
    42     2
    43     2
    44     2
    45     2
    46     2
    47     2
    48     2
    49     2
    50     2
    51     2
    52     2
    53     2
    54     2
    55     2
    56     2
    57     2
    58     2
    59     2
    60     2
    61     2
    62     2
    63     2
    64     2
    65     2
    66     2
    67     2
    68     2
    69     2
    70     2
    71     2
    72     3
    73     3
    74     3
    75     4
    76     5
    77     6
    78     7
    79     8
    79     9
    80    10
    80    11
    80    12
    80    13
    80    14
    80    15
    79    16
    79    17
    79    18
    78    19
    78    20
    78    21
    77    22
    77    23
    77    24
    76    25
    76    26
    76    27
    75    28
    75    29
    75    30
    74    31
    74    32
    74    33
    73    34
    73    35
    73    36
    73    37
    73    38
    72    39
    72    40
    72    41
    72    42
    72    43
    72    44
    73    45
    73    46
    73    47
    74    48
    75    49
    76    50
    77    51
    78    52
    79    53
    80    53
    81    54
    82    54
    83    55
    84    55
    85    56
    86    56
    87    57
    88    57
    89    57
    90    58
    91    58
    92    58
    93    58
    94    59
    95    59
    96    59
    97    59
    98    59
    99    59
   100    59
   101    59
   102    59
   103    59
   104    59
   105    59
   106    59
   107    59
   108    59
   109    59
   110    59
   111    59
   112    58
   113    58
   114    58
   115    58
   116    57
   117    57
   118    57
   119    56
   120    56
   121    56
   122    55
   123    55
   124    54
   125    53
   126    53
   127    52
   128    51
   129    51
   130    50
   131    49
   132    48
   132    47
   133    46
   133    45
   133    44
   133    43
   133    42
   133    41
   133    40
   133    39
   133    38
   132    37
   132    36
   132    35
   131    34
   131    33
   131    32
   131    31
   130    30
   130    29
   130    28
   130    27
   129    26
   129    25
   128    24
   128    23
   127    22
   127    21
   127    20
   127    19
   126    18
   126    17
   126    16
   126    15
   126    14
   126    13
   126    12
   126    11
   126    10
   126     9
   127     8
   128     7
   129     6
   130     5
   131     4
   132     3
   133     3
   134     2
   135     2
   136     2
   137     2
   138     2
   139     2
   140     2
   141     2
   142     2
   143     2
   144     2
   145     2
   146     2
   147     2
   148     2
   149     2
   150     2
   151     2
   152     2
   153     2
   154     2
   155     2
   156     2
   157     2
   158     2
   159     2
   160     2
   161     2
   162     2
   163     2
   164     2
   165     2
   166     2
   167     2
   168     1
   169     1
   170     1
   171     1
   172     1
```

Matrix 2:

```
   173     3
   172     3
   171     3
   170     2
   169     2
   168     2
   167     2
   166     2
   165     2
   164     2
   163     2
   162     2
   161     2
   160     2
   159     2
   158     2
   157     2
   156     2
   155     2
   154     2
   153     2
   152     2
   151     2
   150     2
   149     2
   148     2
   147     2
   146     2
   145     2
   144     2
   143     2
   142     2
   141     2
   140     2
   139     2
   138     2
   137     2
   136     2
   135     3
   134     3
   133     3
   132     3
   131     4
   130     4
   129     4
   128     5
   127     6
   127     7
   127     8
   126     9
   127    10
   127    11
   127    12
   127    13
   127    14
   126    15
   127    16
   127    17
   127    18
   127    19
   127    20
   127    21
   128    22
   128    23
   128    24
   128    25
   129    26
   129    27
   129    28
   130    29
   130    30
   130    31
   131    32
   131    33
   131    34
   132    35
   132    36
   132    37
   132    38
   133    39
   133    40
   133    41
   133    42
   133    43
   132    44
   132    45
   132    46
   131    47
   130    48
   129    49
   128    50
   127    51
   126    52
   125    53
   124    54
   123    54
   122    55
   121    55
   120    55
   119    56
   118    56
   117    57
   116    58
   115    58
   114    59
   113    59
   112    59
   111    59
   110    60
   109    60
   108    60
   107    60
   106    60
   105    60
   104    60
   103    60
   102    60
   101    60
   100    60
    99    60
    98    60
    97    60
    96    60
    95    59
    94    59
    93    59
    92    59
    91    59
    90    58
    89    58
    88    57
    87    57
    86    56
    85    56
    84    55
    83    55
    82    54
    81    54
    80    53
    79    52
    78    51
    77    50
    76    49
    75    48
    74    47
    73    46
    73    45
    73    44
    73    43
    73    42
    73    41
    73    40
    73    39
    73    38
    73    37
    73    36
    74    35
    74    34
    74    33
    75    32
    75    31
    75    30
    76    29
    76    28
    76    27
    77    26
    77    25
    77    24
    78    23
    78    22
    78    21
    79    20
    79    19
    80    18
    80    17
    80    16
    81    15
    81    14
    81    13
    81    12
    81    11
    81    10
    80    10
    79     9
    79     8
    78     7
    77     6
    76     5
    75     4
    74     4
    73     3
    72     3
    71     2
    70     2
    69     2
    68     1
    67     2
    66     2
    65     2
    64     2
    63     2
    62     2
    61     2
    60     2
    59     2
    58     2
    57     2
    56     2
    55     2
    54     2
    53     2
    52     2
    51     2
    50     2
    49     2
    48     2
    47     2
    46     2
    45     2
    44     2
    43     2
    42     2
    41     2
    40     2
    39     2
    38     2
    37     2
    36     2
    35     2
    34     2
    33     2
    32     2
    31     2
    30     2
    29     2
    28     2
    27     2
    26     2
    25     2
    24     2
    23     2
    22     2
    21     2
    20     2
    19     2
    18     2
    17     2
    16     2
    15     2
    14     2
    13     2
    12     2
    11     2
    10     2
     9     2
     8     2
     7     2
     6     2
     5     2
     4     2
     3     2
     2     2
     1     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark everything above one curve and mark everything below the other curve. Then you can get the area between the curves by finding where there are two marks.

You should take a look at this question [Similarity measures between curves?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27861/similarity-measures-between-curves)